# Need help for count array angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have array like this

```
vm.name =['A','A','B','B','C','C','C'];
```

I do like this to count item

```
vm.a =[];
vm.b=[];
vm.c=[];

for(var i =0;i<vm.name.length;i++){
  if(vm.name[i] ==='A'){
    vm.a.push(vm.name[i])
  }
  if(vm.name[i] ==='B'){
    vm.b.push(vm.name[i])
  }
  if(vm.name[i] ==='C'){
    vm.c.push(vm.name[i])
  }
}
```

and render in HTML

```
{{vm.a.length}} //2
{{vm.b.length}} //2
{{vm.c.length}} //3
```

But I don't think it is good. If you have a better way, please tell me.

Comment: I you only need to count the number of character occurrences, You could also use a map/dictionary that maps a character to its frequency.

Answer (score 4):

You can create these arrays dynamically using this beautiful function called [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) :)

```
vm.name = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'];

vm = vm.name.reduce(function(obj, cur) {
  obj[cur.toLowerCase()] = obj[cur.toLowerCase()] || []
  obj[cur.toLowerCase()].push(cur)
  return obj;
}, vm)

console.log(vm.b.length)
console.log(vm.c.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `switch` instead of `if` conditions in a scenario like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < vm.name.length; i++) {
    switch (vm.name[i]) {
        case "A":
            vm.a.push(vm.name[i])
            break;
        case "B":
            vm.b.push(vm.name[i])
            break;
        case "C":
            vm.c.push(vm.name[i])
            break;
        default:
            console.log("no such type")
    }
}
```